# Pattern match over List with subclass entries

Tags: scala, dictionary, polymorphism, pattern-matching

I created an abstract base class as follows:

```
abstract class parent
```

Then I went ahead and created two case classes inheriting from the parent class:

```
case class child1(name:String,category:String) extends parent

case class child2(name:String,category1:String,category2:String) extends parent
```

Then for kicks I created a list of type parent and appended child1 and child2 to it:

```
val childList = List[parent]()

scala> child1("Child","One") :: child2("Child","Two","dhshs")::childList
res2: List[parent] = List(child1(Child,One), child2(Child,Two,dhshs))
```

So far so good, the List[Parent] has the two child types in it.

Now, I want to traverse the List and based on the underlying type of the child, do something special for that particular type. So I do this:

```
scala> res2 map {case child1 => "Child1";case child2 => "Child2"}
```

I expected to see a `List[String]("Child1","Child2")`, instead I got the following:

```
<console>:15: error: unreachable code
              res2 map {case child1 => "Child1";case child2 => "Child2"}
```

Now for some more kicks, I did the following:

```
scala> res2 map {r => r match {case child1 => "Child1"}}
res8: List[java.lang.String] = List(Child1, Child1)

scala> res2 map {case child1 => "Child1"}
res9: List[java.lang.String] = List(Child1, Child1)
```

As you can see, I got "Child1" as my List entry, even for "child2" I get a Child1.

Pretty confused, can somebody tell me whats going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here: child1 and child2 are new variables created to house the result.

```
res2 map {case child1 => "Child1";case child2 => "Child2"}
```

try this:

```
res2 map {case x:child1 => "Child1";case y:child2 => "Child2"}
```

`x` and `y` are the variables with the associated types `child1` and `child2` respectively.

Comment: To clarify, when you merely create a pattern variable, be it `child1` or `child2`, you have not constrained those pattern variables (their allowed bindings) at all. Hence the first one binds to _any_ value (a.k.a a value of type `Any`!) and thus there is no way the second `case` clause can match. As Korefn illustrates, by using the `case name: Type =>` notation you can distinguish classes `child1` from `child2`. Lastly, `trait`s, `class`es (including `abstract class`es) and `object`s should have names that begin with an upper-case character.

Comment: Also you could use a `\`child1\`` and `\`child2\`` (with ticks)

Comment: @indonnie `case _:'child1'` with ticks throws match error for `map` and `foreach` unless one uses `collect`. @Randall well put.